# How to pull data from a Google Sheet to display them as product windows in a wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, web, google-sheets, integration

I have a site Im building and have data about products in a google sheet. I want to display them on the site as separate items.
This is not supposed to be a database where the website communicates with the sheet back and forth. Only pull data from the sheet on load. So that when I change the content of the sheet, the products displayed on the site change too.

Please help. I want to add I have mediocre programming skills and know javascript fairly well.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Install visualizer plugin. It is used to get data from CSV. After this perform following step by step.

Step 1: Add a new chart and select which style to use. With the plugin active, you'll get access to a new Visualizer tab within your dashboard.
Step 2: Import the data from Google Sheets.
Step 3: Display your new chart in WordPress.

Comment: Im sorry but Visualizer does not help my problem.